# Show buttons just when the mouse is hovering the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created a `mvc5` application with table, is there an option that when user go over (hover) the table with the mouse he could see the buttons in the table?

The table is defined like below:

```
  <tbody id="dataTable">
            <tr id="emptyRow" style="display: none;">
                <td>@Html.TextBox("name")</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox1")</td>

                <
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr data-id="@item.Id">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.checkBox1)
                    </td>

                    <td>


                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the following CSS should work

```
#dataTable .actions-default { display: none; }
#dataTable:hover .actions-default { display: block; }
```

Comment: css is always a better way.